# Как мне передать переменную из метода в другой класс

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно передать айпи (через метод getInetAddress()) в класс клиента.

```
@Override
 public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final ExecutorService executeIt = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    try {
        while (!server.isClosed()) {
            server = new ServerSocket(3345);//нужно предать этот сокет
            Socket client = server.accept();
            executeIt.execute(new MonoThreadClientHandler(client));

        }
        executeIt.shutdown();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Эта страна явно катится в пропасть :(

Comment: @Barmaley, я понимаю такую реакцию, но до меня что то не доходит(

Comment: В какой класс? Есть ли в этом классе метод принимающий ваш сокет? Когда надо передать? Принимающий класс синглтон или прототип? Если прототип, есть ли в представленном вами классе объект этого класса? Старайтесь выкладывать достаточно информации.

Comment: @Виктор Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Евгений вот так Client.setIp(server.getInetAddress())

Answer (score 2):

Делается так (более-менее правильно и более-менее концептуально без упаси боже глобальных ссылок, синглтонов и проч. ужаса ужасного, но и без красот навроде интерфейсов, rxJava и т.д.):

1. У вас `AsyncTask`, при его создании в конструктор передаете объект класса куда вы хотите что-то положить
2. Что-то делаете в `doingBackground()`
3. По завершении вызывается `onPostExecute()` - там вы и кладете ваш результат в объект полученный в конструкторе

За скобками оставляю самоочевидные вещи навроде сеттера, который должен быть в вашем объекте и что его надо сделать приватным членом вашего `AsyncTask` иначе его не достать в `onPostExecute` и что надо передать в `onPostExecute()` результат работы `doingBackground` ну и бла-бла-бла...

*Господи, помоги мне все это пережить...*