# android как обновить listview во фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, adapter

В окно с *TabLayout* загружаются 2 фрагмента, нужно при выборе пункта "Удалить" вызвать *AsyncTask* и после выполнить *notifyDataSetChanged()* у адаптера. *AsyncTask* находится в отдельном файле. Сам запрос на сервере срабатывает, а как добраться к  адаптеру во фрагменте не знаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это окно наследуется от главного окна в котором есть метод :

```
public void showItemPopupMenu(View view){
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (this, view);
        String ac=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        final String[] iteminfo= TextUtils.split(view.getTag().toString(),":");//listName, itemId, tag
        final String listname=iteminfo[0];
        uid=iteminfo[1];
        itemtag=iteminfo[2];

        final SharedPreferences shpa=getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(ac.equals("userFavs")) {
            action="remove";
            menu.inflate(R.menu.items_list_delete_action);
        }
        else{
            action="add";
            menu.inflate (R.menu.items_list_add_action);

        }
        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                new addDeleteItemsToFavs(getApplicationContext(),sh,itemtag).execute(uid,action,listname);
                return false;
            }
        });
        menu.show();
    }
```

Участок разметки элемента списка

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/items_list_actions_button"
            android:src="@drawable/dotspopupmenu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="showItemPopupMenu"
            />
```

**addDeleteItemsToFavs.java**

```
public class addDeleteItemsToFavs extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {
        uid = args[0];
        action = args[1];
        listName=args[2];

        HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<>();
        params1.put("addDeleteItemsToFav", "1");

        webRequest webRequest = new webRequest();

        if (true) {
            shp=ctx.getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO,MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (shp.contains("auth_type")) {
                if(shp.getString("auth_type","").equals("user")){
                    favsowner="user";
                    favsownerid=shp.getString("userid","");
                }
                if(shp.getString("auth_type","").equals("seller")){
                    favsowner="seller";
                    favsownerid=shp.getString("sellerid","");
                }
                params1.put("owner", favsowner);
                params1.put("ownerid", favsownerid);
                params1.put("listName", listName);
                params1.put("itemid", uid);
                params1.put("action", action);
            }
            return webRequest.makeRequest(Pathes.ajax, "POST", params1);
        }
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //(Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
            if (!result.equals("no response")) {
              //тут не могу получить адаптер списка во фрагменте
            }

        }
    }
}
```

На [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745764/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81) страницу попрошу не ссылаться, т.к там нет ответа на мой вопрос. Мне нужно получить доступ к адаптеру во фрагменте, чтобы вызвать *notifyDataSetChanged()* и всё.

Comment: Если не добавите код, врядли кто-то сможет помочь

Comment: может быть я копаю не совсем в ту сторону. есть ведь вариант установить tag на фрагмент, а получив фрагмент по тегу можно вызвать метод. но это тоже не допру, где этот тег ставится

Comment: нет никаких вариантов?

Comment: отметили ваше сообщение как дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745764/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81 этого сообщения

Comment: да какой это дубликат???

Comment: Я понимаю, для таких неучей как мы ответы Бармалея весьма сложные, но раз он отметил дубликатом, постарайтесь вникнуть в его ответ, там наверняка есть решение)

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите реализацию Async'а в свой фрагмент, там где у вас определен адаптер. Тогда в onPostExecute вы сможете его обновить.

Comment: уже решил проблему. ошибка была в том что я пытался обновлять адаптер "снаружи" него. а надо было вешать онКлик на кнопку внутри адаптера, вызвать АсинкТаск, получить его ответ методом .get(), удалить из коллекции нужный элемент и вызвать notifyDataSetChanged(). и все получилось

Comment: Так тоже можно. Не всегда удобно управлять данными из кода реализации адаптера.